# Highlight Specific Columns in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to highlight Background color of specific columns in crystal report. That specific columns should be passed by program.

My scenario - monthly Employee Attendance sheet.. highlight all Sunday columns in report.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the background color of a column if you use the Format Editor > Border > Background
Use the condition format if you need to highlight based on a specific value such as Sunday.